# Devexpress Date Range Editor

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress

I'd like to build a repository item for Date Range Editing withing a single data grid cell.
Ideally, I'd like to have 2 calendars side by side in the popup editor, for start/end dates.
And a simple range text when the editor is closed. (ie: 1/1/2001 - 5/1/2001)

Has anyone done this already?
I don't know enough about the repository items/popup architecture to know where to start.
All of the examples I've seen just extend the TextEdit item, and don't show custom popups.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to create this editor based on [Popup Container Edit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument612). A good example how to create a popup editor with a custom functionality can be found [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E2663.aspx).